# Sharing constants between Struts Java and Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts, constants

I have a `Struts + Jsp + Java` application and I have .js files for javascripting my jsp files.
I need to use some (same) constants both in Java and Javascript files.

I have defined the constants in my java classes. I also need to have those constants in my javascript files. Is there a way such that I can use my Java constants in my javascript? What is a good practice?

Right now, I am defining them twice, once in Java classes and then in Javascript files.

Answer (score 2):

At the top of the JSP that includes the .js file, emit a javascript block that declares the javascript constants. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
var myConstant1 = <%= MY_CONSTANT1 %>;
var myConstant2 = <%= MY_CONSTANT2 %>;
</script>
```

This is a **very** simplistic answer - note that you probably shouldn't really be creating a bunch of global variables in JavaScript - you should create one object that wraps all of your constants (see [http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)), but this demonstrates the general concept.

Comment: Thanks. What if I want to use the constant across multiple .js across different jsps? Is there a good approach?